# How can I reach the score target for level 97?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

For as little as it ashames me to admit it, I've actually played 96 levels of this fun little Bejeweled clone wrapped around in its freemium economy bullshit. The reviews mentioned that level 65 would've been really hard, and it was, but nothing dumb luck eventually couldn't solve; the goal was clear and it was obvious to understand how to reach it. Achieving it was the challenge.

That's not so true for level 97.

The 95-110 level pack, "Salty Canyon", introduces the time bomb. Basically it's candies that explode if not cleared in a number of turns. When a candy explodes the game ends immediately. Now, level 97 has a really small bomb-shaped field where bombs drop as you destroy them; you only have 25 moves and you must reach 100,000 points. Spoiler alert: that's a *whole lot* of points. Destroying a bomb is only 3k. A perfect run would destroy two candies every other turn for a total of 72k, with 28k more points to be scored from combinations. That is... really hard to do though.

My best run so far reached 90k by destroying bombs almost every turn while creating rather special candies at an alarming pace; the only thing I didn't do was the "hypercube-hypercube" swap.

What am I missing? How am I supposed to score that much?

Comment: For the curious, today's update brought the total amount of levels at about 335.

Comment: The strategy for passing most levels are to make special candies, the more you make the better it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically make combos and assume that sheer luck will take care of the bombs when exploding combos.

Also take the advantage of the fact, that after your last move you have Sugar Rush regardless if you've reached the minimum required. This means that all unexploded combos will explode. Take advantage of that and create as many as you can without bothering to explode them.

Answer (score 1):

This is another "dumb luck" level. Start low, make special candies, and don't worry too much about the bombs. If you can get some combos off, that's about the only way you'll hit it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a frustrating, frustrating level.  I will say that in all my CCS exploits, this is probably the one I spent the most time trying to clear.  If you're stuck, I **[put together a guide here](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/how-do-i-clear-candy-crush-saga-level-97/)** that might help, but I'll summarize a few key points.

1. **[Roll this level](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/rolling-guide-candy-crush-saga/)** by backing out and coming back in until you've got a 3 or better vertical match in one of the right two columns.  (I had to educate badp about rolling - he was unaware this was a thing.  It's very, very useful!)  Without this as your starting position, you're very, very likely to lose.
2. Focus on Wrapped candies - these are created by a L or T shape of 6 candies.  You want to detonate these near the middle of the board, where they can do the most damage.  If they fall to the bottom, they won't earn you nearly as much score.
3. If you end up with a Color Bomb (five-in-a-row, the one that has multicolored sprinkles), try to match it with another special candy.  Beggars can't be choosers here, so match it however you can.
4. When you're low on moves (say, 5 or fewer) ignore the bombs completely and focus on special candies, which will auto-detonate when you run out of turns.
5. You *should* focus on the bombs, as they're worth the most.  When you are low on bombs (one or none remaining) try to make a vertical match in one of the innermost columns - this will drop the new bombs into a position where they will be easier to match and combo.  Honestly, I more or less ignored the far right and far left columns altogether.
6. Striped candies are pretty worthless.  If it's the best move you have, take it, but don't go out of your way to create or detonate them.

Even rolling through "bad" starts and playing as soon as I had lives available, this still took me a solid week of play to clear.  It's one of the hardest levels I've played to date.

I had about a dozen really frustrating close calls where I was within 5,000 points of winning and lost anyhow.  There's just such a small amount of room to work with here and the score total is so high that the odds are really stacked against you.

Comment: tbh, it's got nothing on... 117, I think. That's where I stopped playing eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I posted my strategy for level 97 of Candy Crush [on ReadyGamer here](http://readygamer.com/candy-crush-level-97-tips/).

Basically, I focused on making striped+wrapped candy combos as early and often as possible. I was able to make 2 of these combos and that just about took care of the point objective combined with all the other candy crushing.

Aside from that, keep track of the turns left on your bombs and try to make wrapped candies when in doubt. Don't make striped candies unless you see a possible striped+wrapped combo in the making, or if the striped is going to help you take out a soon-to-explode bomb.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comply with our self-promotion and link policies :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Beating level 97](http://candycrushsagaallhelp.blogspot.pt/)

Colourbombs won't give enough points, a wrapped candy alone will give a ton of points.

Aim for the  stripped+wrap combo immediately if possible, it'll get you around 10-15k points

If not possible, aim for the timed bombs

Use wrapped candies immediately as they grant quite a few points

The best combo:

- 2 wrapped candies combined together, 25-50k points

Comment: I think there is a bug in the Android version. Mixing the glitter ball with a bomb only nets me 30 points whereas other users are reporting 3k points per equivalent coloured candy on the screen.